# Jekyll: an _include which lists posts of a given category

Tags: include, jekyll, posts

If I have two very similar ways of listing posts of two different categories:

```
{% if site.categories.News | size > 0 %}
    <ul>
        {% for post in site.categories.News %}
            <li><a href="{{ post.url }}">{{ post.title }}</a></li>
        {% endfor %}
    </ul>
{% else %}
<p>There are no news posts available</p>
{% endif %}


{% if site.categories.Blog | size > 0 %}
    <ul>
        {% for post in site.categories.Blog %}
            <li><a href="{{ post.url }}">{{ post.title }}</a></li>
        {% endfor %}
    </ul>
{% else %}
<p>There are no blog posts available</p>
{% endif %}
```

It makes me feel like this could be an _include, where the category could be passed as a parameter to include e.g. `{% include listposts.html category=News %}`

However because of the `site.categories.(News/Blog)` syntax,  am unsure how to pass in the category variable, `site.categories.(include.category)` would not work, as `CAT` in `site.categories.CAT` is a literal and not a variable. Does anyone know how I can make these two similar blocks of code a single _include that canbe passed the category as a parameter?

Comment: Try to access them as a key in an array like site.categories['News']

Answer (score 2):

Your include parameter should look like this: `{% include listposts.html category=site.categories.News %}`

Then your `listposts.html` file can through them like this:

```
{% if include.category %}
  <ul>
    {% for post in include.category %}
      <li><a href="{{ post.url }}">{{ post.title }}</a></li>
    {% endfor %}
  </ul>
{% else %}
  <p>There are no blog posts available</p>
{% endif %}
```